# How to do Masking month value in Date using C# Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

Consider my Date string value is **25-12-1993**, i just want to hide the month value as **25-##-1993**, if date string is **25-Mar-1993** i need to show **25-###-1993** using C# **regular expression**.

Comment: this can be only achieved if date time is used as string, but if you're trying to that in datetime object it is not possible.

Comment: Hi, i am having the date value as string, not as a datetime object

Comment: Use ToString() :             DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("25-12-1993", "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string output = date.ToString("dd-##-yyyy");

Comment: Thanks that will work, but i just want to know is there any possibility to do this kind of masking using C# regular expression

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-");
regex.Replace(yourDateString, "-##-");
```

This finds a two digit number between 01 and 12 between 2 hyphens, and replaces with 2 hash symbols between 2 hyphens.

Comment: if date string is 25-Mar-1993 i need to show 25-###-1993

Answer (score 1):

```
string text = "25-12-1993";
string result = Regex.Replace(text, @"-(.+?)-", "-##-");
```

Output:

```
25-##-1993
```

Comment: if user has a string of 25-ab-1993 which is not a date string your code will still replace it.

Comment: Yes I know, in case the date comes like 25-May-1991

Comment: if date string is 25-Mar-1993 i need to show 25-###-1993

Comment: @JAMDHA FARUS Based on his requirement, just added ## . Maybe he needs to sort something later with the ## so I can't break it with ###

Comment: Based on number of character in month part, i need to add number of #

Comment: @JAMDHAFARUS would you please ask this question in a new thread, so everyone can help

Answer (score 0):

@jdweng solution is best but here is regex solution

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("25-12-1993", "dd-MM-yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string output = Regex.Replace(date.ToShortDateString(), @"(\/\d{2}\/)+", "-##-", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
```

Comment: Why convert to a DateTime then back to a string?

Comment: just as sample to convert a real DateTime object to string with regex .replace nothing else